# problems with activity.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a activity xml file, when i run it i get 2 errors.
activity_forget_and_change_password.xml:2: AAPT: error: unbound prefix.
activity_forget_and_change_password.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

Hope someone can help  me.
I have search internet and i cant find the right answer to my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="xxxxxxxxx.ForgetAndChangePasswordActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FireBase Change Password"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/label">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Mode"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


</LinearLayout>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context="xxxxxxx.ForgetAndChangePasswordActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FireBase Change Password"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/label">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Mode"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you mean to post two XML files in one code snippet?

Comment: That's the same layout twice, and it should not be giving the stated error, as is. Are you sure you're looking at the right file? Are you sure that's exactly how you have it in your project currently?

Comment: yes i have 2 LinearLayout in the same.

Comment: Do you mean that what you have posted is all in one XML file? That is, you have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` a second time, followed by another `<LinearLayout>` with the same content as above, repeated?

Comment: it was that in the tutorials i try

Comment: You can't do that. That tutorial is wrong, or maybe it's just a "typo" there. I really wouldn't think that that's the error it would give in Android Studio, but that's an invalid XML file. You can only have one root in your layout. If you want that same `<LinearLayout>` twice, then put them both inside another `ViewGroup`; e.g., another vertical `<LinearLayout>`. And get rid of that second `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

Comment: here can you see your self : http://www.maddeveloper.in/2018/01/email-signin-with-help-of-firebase-1.html

Comment: Yeah, they just accidentally pasted it twice. Notice that none of the other layouts are like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your TextInputLayout to androidx component:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/label">
```

And add support libraries to your app build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Still the same error.
activity_forget_and_change_password.xml:52: AAPT: error: mismatched tag.
activity_forget_and_change_password.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

Comment: Did you modify the closing tag as well?